# Convert Powershell Function into Expression

Tags: powershell

I need to execute script as Expression using iex. Is there some way to convert a huge function into expression? It should be one-liner with commands separated by `;`, as I understand.

Comment: Invoke-Expression takes a string and executes it as code? What are you trying to do exactly and do you have an example? Any code can be shown as one line. Does not make it readable or a good idea.

Comment: I have a huge function that takes about 2k lines. I need to find a way to convert it into one-line expression which can be executed by iex.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand _why_? You are just repeating the question. Why does it have to be one line. Save the function in a file and call the script with powershell.exe ?

Comment: I have vbs script which at some point calls powershell script. I can drop the script to file and execute it, but I want to do it fileless. That's how the question was born :)

Comment: So have the string in vbs and save it to a file at run time for execution. You can just run it straight from the cmd line but I worry it would be too long and fail as cmd has a character limit. Also, not realistic, just run the whole thing in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that with encoding:

```
$string = {(Get-WindowsFeature).Where{$PSItem.Installed}}.ToString()
$encodedcommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($string))
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand $encodedcommand
```

You can encode a function that way also.

Comment: My script is too huge to fit into command line, so this trick won't do the deal.